# Why is cuprous oxide a p-type semiconductor?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, semiconductors

[Wikipedia — Copper(I) oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_oxide) says $\ce{Cu2O}$ has semiconducting properties without any explanation.
Nolan [[1](https://doi.org/10.1039/b611969g)] talks about $\ce{Cu^+}$ vacancies making copper(I) oxide an extrinsic p-type semiconductor, but provides no explanation how these vacancies (I call them “*atomic holes*”) travel resulting in electrical conductivity.

I understand how silicone doped with boron results in an electron hole so it's a p-type semiconductor.
But for $\ce{Cu2O}$ the explanation I found is that one $\ce{Cu+}$ ion is oxidized to $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and to maintain electrical neutrality another $\ce{Cu+}$ ion is removed creating a hole which results in electrical conductivity and a p-type conductor is formed.

However, I don't find this explanation convincing.
For $\ce{Si}$ doped with $\ce{B}$ an electron hole was created and I can imagine that hole travelling.
But in $\ce{Cu2O}$ the hole is a vacancy as one $\ce{Cu^+}$ leaves the lattice. Such a big “*atomic hole*” can't appreciably travel for conducting electricity.

So, how is $\ce{Cu2O}$ an extrinsic p-type semiconductor?
What is really happening at the atomic level, namely:

1. What are the holes here responsible for p-type semiconducting?
2. Is $\ce{Cu2O}$ doped with something, since p-type or n-type semiconductors are usually made by introducing a dopant?

#### Reference

1. Nolan, M.; Elliott, S. D. The p-type conduction mechanism in $\ce{Cu2O}$: a first principles study. *Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.* **2006**, 8 (45), 5350. DOI: [10.1039/b611969g](https://doi.org/10.1039/b611969g).

Comment: IMHO $\ce{Cu2O}$ as not fully stoichiometric oxide is doped by $\ce{Cu^2+}$, which acts as a  hole when the extra positive charge is effectively moving among copper atoms.

Comment: @Poutnik (a)So the reason i found(see 'My confusion' in my answer above) is wrong . But that same reason was implied in the research paper (though not clarified). (b)please elaborate what u mean by "which acts as a hole when the extra positive charge is effectively moving among copper atoms"...?(c)Is it just an opinion or you have  some sources...just asking...?

Comment: I do not claim I am an expert for semiconductors so I can be wrong. // I mean $\ce{Cu^{2+}-Cu^{+}-Cu^{+} ->  Cu^{+}-Cu^{2+}-Cu^{+} -> Cu^{+}-Cu^{+}-Cu^{2+}}$

Comment: Ok thanks, but let's  wait for some more inputs from other people....

Comment: $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and a $\ce{Cu+}$ vacancy take place of 2 $\ce{Cu+}$ to keep neutrality, but 2+ charge is movable among Cu  1+ charges.

Comment: Yes I get u but O2- ions are there also that may produce an hindrance to such charge exchanges.I mean it may be a less contributing reason. But, as wikipedia quotes about Cu2O , "In the history of semiconductor physics, Cu2O is one of the most studied materials, and many experimental semiconductor applications have been demonstrated first in this material" , there should be a more dominant factor at play.

Comment: Cu2O acts similar to a p type semiconductor due to the lack of an election, similar as in a standard p type semiconductor. In a standard p type semiconductor, the selection hole is present in the bond pair between B and Si. In this case, it is in the valence shell of Cu ( Cu2+: 3d9; Cu+: 3d10)

Answer (score 1):

The $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion you call "atomic hole" is responsible for the p-type conductivity. The way to understand is would be a $\ce{Cu+}$ ion with a h+ (hole) associated with it. Conductivity may occur by the hole jumping between neighbouring ions if this association energy can be overcome. Resulting in a temperature-activated hopping process. The hole is moving from copper to copper, not the entire $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ion.